# alert from php page that data already received from arduino

Tags: php, arduino-uno

I'm currently doing a project regarding an attendance system using arduino uno and Ethernet shield. For now I have successfully saved the id I get from arduino to the database. My problem is how to make an alert or popup message that says the data has been received and stored in the database every time I receive data from arduino.

Thank you.

**Below is my arduino code:**

```
if (client.connect(myServer, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to Database server");
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    client.print("GET /school/inc/jaripelajar.php?P_ID=");
    client.print(P_ID); 
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.137.1");
    client.println("User-Agent: arduino-ethernet");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
}
```

**php code**

```
// GET request
if (isset($_GET['P_ID'])){
    $data1 = $_GET['P_ID'];
}
else{
    //echo "Data not received";
}

// Initialize connection to MySQL database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "school";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully <br>";


//Insert into database
$data1_sql = "INSERT INTO test (P_ID) VALUES ($data1);";
$data1_query = mysqli_query($conn, $data1_sql);
```

Comment: Depends on what you're building to consume/display this data, are you building a website, an API, or even a command line process?

Comment: @Scuzzy hi, i am building a website system.using php and html

Comment: I think what you're going to need is something client side that polls / works in the background, this is going to get terribly broad but look into either web workers or write some javascript to hit a php script that can generate an API response (Ajax, JSON, XHR etc etc)